# Looking for a fantasy book about a girl with unexpected tattoos

Tags: story-identification, medieval

She was the only one with these tattoos who wasn't sacrificed. I think she became an enforcer, the leader of her tower. She was ridiculed by his peers for allowing different species in. Types of people included lion-like, bird people, and telepaths. I think there were people in power when were elf-like. I only read one book but I think it was a series.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you remember any more details - for example, where/when did you read this book, was it written in English, hardback or paperback, any character names, length of the book, was it set in an imaginary world? There are some useful checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394) which might help to jog your memory; please [edit] in any extra details you can remember. Thanks!

Comment: Per comment by FuzzyBoots on first answer, duplicate status was confirmed by the OP at some point.

Answer (score 3):

I would [also](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176627/30870) say the **Chronicles of Elantra** by Michelle Sagara.  Specifically:

> She was the only one with these tattoos who wasn't sacrificed

While Kaylin was a child, other children were sacrificed (killed).  She was the only survivor of that group.

> she became an enforcerer

Yes.  What we would know as a police officer.  She is already a Hawk (their name in the books) at the start of the first book.

> the leader of her tower?

The Hawklord runs the Tower of Law, where the Hawks work.

> included lion like, bird people, and telepaths

The Leontines are lion-like.  The Aerians are bird-like.  The Tha'alani are telepaths.

> seems like there were people in power when were elf like

The Barrani.

> I think it was a series

Everything fits the Elantra series.  I would think an earlier book if the Dragons weren't featured, but I don't think that the Tha'alani were in the first book or two.  They were important in the fourth book and have appeared regularly since.

Comment: Confirmed by the querent in an edit to their question, "thanks for the answers looks like I got it."

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like one of the **Chronicles of Elantra** books by  **[Michelle](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/s/michelle-sagara/) [Sagara](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/s/michelle-sagara/)**, could be any of them or a short story

> These follow the adventures of Private Kaylin Neya, a young woman who serves the Hawks in the towering Halls of Law. She’s Elantra’s version of a police officer, a mortal in a city ruled by Dragons.

Kaylin was raised in a fiefdom called Nightshade and escaped to Elantra. She has multiple tattoos on her body. She is human (probably) but there are Leontines, Barrani, and Aerians as well.

Chronicles of Elantra

0.5. Cast in Moonlight (2012)

1. Cast in Shadow (2005)
2. Cast in Courtlight (2006)
3. Cast In Secret (2007)
4. Cast In Fury (2008)
5. Cast in Silence (2009)
6. Cast in Chaos (2010)
7. Cast in Ruin (2011)
8. Cast in Peril (2012)
9. Cast in Sorrow (2013)
10. Cast in Flame (2014)
11. Cast in Honor (2015)
12. Cast in Flight (2016)
13. Cast in Deception (2018)

Comment: Why do you feel they match?

Comment: Confirmed by the querent in an edit to their question, "thanks for the answers looks like I got it."